# Why is my CSS not loading?

Tags: theme-development, css

I have the following code on my wordpress page but none of it is being formatted by the style.css file. Everything is in a folder titles 'Web Services' that i place directly into the wp-content/themes folder. All it does is print the plain text.

Header.php:

```
    <meta name="description" content = "Welcome to Flier Web Design!" />
    <meta name="keywords" content = "Premium, Web, Design, Web Design, fast, easy" />
    <meta name="author" content = "Corey" />
    <title>Our PHP Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        <p>LOGO</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hsubcribe">
        <p>Header Subscribe</p>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <p>navbar</p>
    </div>
```

sidebar:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<p>sidebar</p>
</div>
```

footer.php:

```
<div id="footer">
<p>footer</p>
```

functions.php:

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div id="contentleft">
<style>font-size: 300px;</style>
    <p>indexpage</p>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Web Services
Author: Corey
Description: First Template
Version: 1.1
License: None
License URI: http://flierwebdesign.com
Text Domain: flierwebdesign
*/

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: yellow;
font-family:Calibiri, Arial, Tahoma;

}
#header {
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
}
#logo {
width: 400px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#hsubscribe {
width: 400px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#navbar {
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
}
#content {
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;

}
#contentleft {
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
}
#sidebar {
width: 300px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#footer{
font-size: 300px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `wp_head()` - check out one of the default Twenty XX themes for an example of how templates should look.

Comment: thanks. Will definitely be looking through those themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `wp_head()` hook before closing of `<head>` tag hook at header where all the enqueued files will be added dynamically. Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/

Also don't forget to put `wp_footer()` at your footer.php file. See
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: thanks. I was on this for 4 hours editing the functions.php and style.css files trying to find out what I was missing. I was following a normal php tutorial and wanted to test it, but WordPress was already installed on my server so I wasn't sure what was missing.

Comment: I added:



    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>


and

    
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>

but still shows unformatted Maybe I should just restart from an existing template.

Comment: you need to enqueue your styles and scripts

Comment: See some examples here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: thanks. The enqueue is really confusing. Had it pointing to the wrong directory. This was killing me!